# Set up nginx ingress controller on Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am unable to figure out how to set up ingress controller on Kubernetes cluster (not minikube). Every nginx ingress setup I followed yielded to an error and controller not set up properly. Basically, I want an equivalent command to minikube addons enable ingress.
Thanks.

Edit 1->

I am following the installation steps mentioned in https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/
I have tried out the baremetal, cloud and a couple of more ways to install nginx-ingress controller.

In a couple of installations, External IP was stuck on  for ever. In the cloud installation, while hosting the ingress service, I encountered the error,

```
Error from server (InternalError): error when creating "kubernetes-custom-scheduler/kubernetes/configuration/services/loki-ingress.yaml": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io": Post "https://ingress-nginx-controller-admission.ingress-nginx.svc:443/networking/v1beta1/ingresses?timeout=10s": dial tcp 10.98.61.194:443: connect: connection refused
```

I am currently using Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster).

I have tried using bare-metal ingress controller from https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/ but it is only for NodePort Service. I need the nginx-ingress controller for Cluster-IP Services.

Comment: At least some actual error message might be helpful

Comment: How exactly you've been trying to deploy it?

Comment: Please check the official [Installation Guide of Nginx Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/)

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I have updated the exact issue.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to install with HELM.

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-helm/

If you do not have helm, then install it first.

https://helm.sh/docs/intro/install/